# Unable to connect to SMTP with PHPMailer but am able to connect on Pingability

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm getting `SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2015-09-01 13:30:34  SMTP connect() failed` when attempting to connect to an Exchange server to send mail with PHPMailer. I don't think it's a problem with the credentials because I used the same credentials to test on pingability.com and I'm able to connect and send without any issues. The openssl extension is enabled as well.

Code I'm using:

```
require_once 'vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$emailer = new PHPMailer();
$emailer->IsSMTP();
$emailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
$emailer->Host = "xxx.xxxxxxx.com";
$emailer->Username = "xxxxx";
$emailer->Password = "xxxxx";
$emailer->Port = 25;
$emailer->isHTML(true);
$emailer->From = "xxx@xxxxxx.com";
$emailer->FromName = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$emailer->Subject = "Reset Your Password";
$emailer->Body = "To reset your password, please visit this link:<br>" . $link;
$emailer->AddAddress( $email );
$emailer->AddAddress( "xxx@xxxxxx.com" );
$emailer->Send();
```

Comment: It is likely the port is incorrect. Why not contact the exchange server and ask them? You might need to use $emailer->SMTPAuth= true;

Comment: I asked and the port is 25.

Comment: I attempted with and without SMTPAuth.

Comment: It's unusual to support auth on port 25; it's usually 587. Also you don't have encryption enabled, and auth without that is also unusual. Look at the gmail example code provided with PHPMailer for reference. Is it likely your ISP blocks PHP email connections? GoDaddy does that, amongst others. Also read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).